# Google-App-Engine MySQL datebase not connecting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine website with PHP and a MySQL instance database attached. I have a database connection file and I can connect the database to the website in the GAE development area but when I deploy the application I am unaware of how to connect them. I have the following code but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
  $host = "unix_socket=/cloudsql/application:instancename";
  $user = "root";
  $password = "password";
  $database = "database";

  $connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database ); 

  if ($connect->connect_errno) 
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $connect->connect_error; 
  }
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: I get this:   {"outcome":false,"message":"Unable to connect."}

Answer (score 1):

Let's just follow along the guidance at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/ ...

I imagine you've already followed https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/#create including the confirmation of the grant of access to that Cloud SQL instance for your App Engine app via the latter's application ID (and that they're in the same geographical region, &c -- all clearly detailed there and at links therefrom).

Now, if what you want to use for your App Engine app is `msqli`, look at the example at that page...:

```
$sql = new mysqli(null,
  'root', // username
  '',     // password
  <database-name>,
  null,
  '/cloudsql/<your-project-id>:<your-instance-name>'
  );
```

See the many differences?  First argument null, password empty string, and the Cloud SQL reference as the **sixth** argument.

Alternatively, if you've purchased an IP address for your Cloud SQL instance, another example at the same URL is

```
$sql = new mysqli('127.0.0.1:3306',
  '<username>',
  '<password>',
  <database-name>
  );
```

but I think the former approach is preferred (and it saves you the modest expense for the IP address -- don't let the example mislead you, the IP address to use would **not** be 127.0.0.1, but whatever you had purchased for your Cloud SQL instance:-).

Yes, a different mix is needed to access MySQL from your local development server than from a deployed appspot.com app -- but I recommend you to read through the example at the URL I've given to see how to turn that to your advantage (using a local MySQL on your development machine when you're just developing locally, and reserving the actual Cloud SQL instance for really deployed apps -- that way, bugs you might have during local development won't break your real database and cause problems!-)

Comment: Thank you for all of that. But I have tried the msqli way you stated and the same problem still happens